# nginx domain regex to include wildcards

Tags: regex, nginx

How do I deny illegal host headers besides all subdomains (wildcard solution) and the main domain with nginx? When using this code below all of the subdomains stop working.

```
if ($host !~* ^(domain.com|*.domain.com)$ ) {
    return 444;
}
```

My server name is:

```
server_name domain.com *.domain.com;
```

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: `^` means "start of string". `^domain.com` will NOT match `foo.domain.com`, because `domain.com` isn't at the start of the string. `|*.` will also not work. `*` is "zero or more of the previous", but you have no previous `|` is not a matching character, it's the regex equivalent of "or".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you:

```
if ($host !~* ^(.+\.)?domain\.com$ ) {
    return 444;
}
```

You need to escape the periods, otherwise they will be interpreted as "any character". You can also simplify the regex a bit by matching an optional subdomain prefix before "domain.com".

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner solution would be to create a separate (default) `server` block for "other" server names:

```
server {
    server_name .domain.com; # shorter form for "domain.com *.domain.com"

    ... # your main config here
}

server {
    listen *:80 default_server;
    server_name "";

    return 444;
}
```